# Mountain bike front derailleur won't shift up

Tags: shifting, derailleur-front

I didn't use my bike for few months. Now the front derailleur won't shift up.
Basically, when I shift to the second gear I hear a "click" then the chain is stuck between the first and the second gear. Futhermore, I can't shift to the third gear I don't hear the "click" and the chain is still stuck between the gears.

The derailleur cage seems fine to me. The cable is not too loose.

this is my first time I try to repair my bike myselft. I don't know what else should I check.

Edit: The chain is not really between the first and the second gear. The chain is more like half on the first gear and half not touching any gear. It feels like the chain is not high enough to reach the second gear.

Edit: The derailleur should be 2mm above the outer chain gear, but mine seems to be 0.5mm above. I don't have the tools today to test it. Maybe this is the problem?

update:While pedalling if force a bit more over the second gear using the shifter on handlebar I can get on the second gear then 2 to 3 works like a charm.

Comment: “The cable is not too loose” – well, everything else about the description sounds like that's precisely what _is_ wrong. How did you judge that it isn't?

Comment: when I shift up the cable has not any more loose. What makes me think the cable is not the problem is that when I try to shift to the third gear the derailleur moves a bit but the chain seems stuck.

Comment: Sure sounds like it needs adjustment to me.

Comment: (Stupid question:  When you try to shift are you turning the crank forward?)

Comment: Yes, I'm turning the crank foward.

Answer (score 2):

First follow the cable run from the shifter to the derailleur and check the cable housing is properly inserted in the shifter and all frame stops. If the housing is not secured the shifter cannot pull the cable to activate the derailleur.

Check the derailleur has not been rotated on the frame. This is easily done by bumping the bike into something. The cage should be parallel to the chainrings

Detach the cable from the derailleur, tension the cable a little by pulling on it with a pair of pliers, work the shifter and make sure it shifts through all gears and pulls in and lets out the cable smoothly.

With the back wheel of the ground, manually pedal and carefully push the derailleur cage out to make sure it will move between the smallest and largest sprockets. If the derailleur range is too limited check the limit adjustments and look for anything jamming the parallelogram.

Reattach the shift cable and follow a guide for derailleur set up and adjustment. Park Tool [has a good one](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment).

Comment: Even if I push the derailleur without using the cable, the chain is stuck at the same place. Between the first and second gear teeth then the derailleur can't move because of the chain. Actually, the chain is stuck between the derailleur cage and the second gear teeth so the derailleur can't go further.